# Bootstrap-based layout - navbar-brand to display img & text inline & aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site for my employer and have run into a little bit of an issue during our "rebranding" stage. The page in question can be found here: http://chargehubdevchris.azurewebsites.net/

The issue is specifically with the index page, and concerns the brand logo / text. The text is using a web font (that we generated) and the logo is an image placed inline within the Navbar-brand class anchor tag.

The img is forcing both elements to drop down about 10px from the desired height, and exceeding the nav's desired height.

The code in question is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img class="homelogo" src="logos/ChargeHub-Logo.png"/><span class="greylogo">Charge</span>Hub</a>
        </div>
```

I've tried to use the "pull-left" class on the img, which then aligns the text properly with the rest of the nav, but leaves the img out of line. I've applied the pull to other elements, attempted adjusting Vertical-align, and even some negative margins. They didn't really accomplish what I wanted, without causing more of a headache down the line.

I have also tried placing them in a div, floating it, setting it to display inline-block, but I couldn't get it to play nicely.

I know I must be missing something probably rather obvious, but I've tried all that I can think of, and everything that I could find online to no avail, and was hoping somebody could help me sort this. It seems like there MUST be an easy way for bootstrap to accomplish this, as I cannot be the first to try!

Answer (score 1):

I did solve this problem in this way.

```
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
    }
```

thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although this is not at all what I wanted, now it just places the logo image at the very top of the page, not inline with the text. As this screenshot shows. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w7royun2gl7jy8/Screenshot%202016-02-12%2009.32.23.png?dl=0

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you using any other css for that tags? It works fine for me, if you can make jsfiddle or can show more at least css I will try to help. Thank you

Comment: Yes there is other css applied to those tags, but I'm not going to dump it all in here... Though as far as the img tag goes, nothing should be conflicting with it. I don't know HOW it worked on your end, but it's not at all working for me. 

I appreciate you trying to help, but I'm just going to replace the text and logo with an image of both.

Comment: You may try to apply the same css to the span tag inside the class="navbar-brand page-scroll" and set margin-left to the width of icon. Like .navbar-brand span { position: absolute; top: 0px; margin-left: (width of icon)px; } Sorry if it won't help you. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your `<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">` element, change the `padding-top` property to make it placed upper.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

I see when you scroll down, some JS code will add navbar-shrink class to the bar. Try to add padding-top modification under this class:

```
.navbar-brand :not(.navbar-shrink) {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried that as well, and it works at the full-size, but all the smaller viewports, or other pages, it breaks the layout, requiring more fixes... seems like there must be a better way. 

Any additional ideas ?

Comment: @Fox Have you tried to do sth in the JS when you scrolling the page down?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.. we do have JS that eases the scrolling to our anchors on the index page, and a couple others. But I didn't write this, and I don't think it's what's causing the issue.